# Split testing (aka A/B testing) on Heroku

Tags: php, heroku, load-balancing, ab-testing

[newbie alert: I'm not using Heroku yet] I would like to set up split testing on Heroku: the best method would be to have two or more variants of my PHP code running (presumably) in different dynos, and to route a configurable percentage of traffic to each (ensuring that once a session has started, subsequent traffic goes to the same variant).

I suppose you could call this a kind of customised load balancer, and I'm happy to write snippets of code to plug into the heroku framework in order to achieve this. But I can't currently see anywhere this could be done.

The people who get this right are Netlify (https://docs.netlify.com/site-deploys/split-testing/#run-a-branch-based-test), but sadly, you can't use Netlify to deploy server-based dynamic web apps.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Is your 'load balancer' written in PHP as well?  Anything blocking you from running a plain A/B testing SDK at that point?

Comment: At the point I posed the question, I didn't have a load balancer and I was struggling to find a plain A/B testing SDK that would do the job I wanted – hence the question. Time has now moved on and I've written my own lightweight framework in PHP, which will operate independently of Heroku.